# How to handle unicode values in JSON strings?

Tags: c++, json, parsing, unicode

I'm writing a JSON parser in C++ and am facing a problem when parsing JSON strings:

The JSON specification states that JSON strings can contain unicode characters in the form of:

```
"here comes a unicode character: \u05d9 !"
```

My JSON parser tries to map JSON strings to `std::string` so usually, one character of the JSON strings becomes one character of the `std::string`. However for those unicode characters, I really don't know what to do:

Should I just put the raw bytes values in my `std::string` like so:

```
std::string mystr;
mystr.push_back('\0x05');
mystr.push_back('\0xd9');
```

Or should I interpret the two characters with a library like `iconv` and store the UTF-8 encoded result in my string instead ?

Should I use a `std::wstring` to store all the characters ? What then on *NIX OSes where `wchar_t` are 4-bytes long ?

I sense something is wrong in my solutions but I fail to understand what. What should I do in that situation ?

Comment: If wchar_t is 4 bytes long, you can just zero-extend... Also, UTF-8 doesn't mean 8-bit characters. Non-ASCII will be stored using multiple bytes in the UTF-8 encoding as well.

Comment: @H2CO3: Sure, indeed. http://json.org states that a *string* can contain **any UNICODE character** but it does not say whether those strings are UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoded. It seems to me that it is UTF-8 encoding with a special representation for UTF-16 characters. One goal of my question is also to make sure of that.

Comment: there's no such thing as "UTF-16 characters". There are Unicode characters which are not part of ASCII, and they are encoded using multiple bytes in UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 as well. The composed-of-multiple-byte-wide-characters strings in UTF-16 and UTF-32 are jsut convenience in order all character to be of the same length.

Comment: @H2CO3: Except that UTF-16 does *not* allow "all character to be of the same length". That's a [common fiction.](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/#conclusions) UTF-16 has surrogate pairs: two "characters" that form a codepoint, just like UTF-8 does.

Comment: @NicolBolas OP obviously has strong mischiefs about this, so I didn't want to overcompilcate the explanation - of course when you have a character that needs those 4 bytes, UTF-16 will act similarly to UTF-8 in the case of non-ASCII characters. And keep calm, [I have read this.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) :)

Comment: JavaScript uses UTF-16, so you need to convert from UTF-16 to whatever you use anyway. The `\u` escape sequences denote UTF-16 code units, not code points.

Comment: @H2CO3: I actually knew about that as well. I'm just surprised that you took the time to post 3 comments with little information when it actually seems you have the knowledge to write a complete and helpful answer. You sure do not owe me (or anyone else here) anything, but after some digging, your comments helped me to realize the difference between codepoints and UTF-8/16/32 encodings. I would for sure have accepted those explanations as an answer. (So Thanks for those comments)

Comment: @Philipp: The section [2.5. Strings](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627) seems to state otherwise. Are you sure ?

Comment: @ereOn: What I mean is that the `\u` escape sequences denote UTF-16 code units, so characters outside the BMP need two such escape sequences.

Comment: @Philipp: Indeed, I missed the paragraph in the RFC that explains that. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After some digging and thanks to [H2CO3's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107329/how-to-handle-unicode-values-in-json-strings#comment17817077_13107329) and [Philipp's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107329/how-to-handle-unicode-values-in-json-strings/13107892#comment17817850_13107329), I finally could understand how this is supposed to work:

Reading the [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627), Section `3. Encoding`:

> 3. Encoding
>
>    JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
>      UTF-8.
>
>    Since the first two characters of a JSON text will always be ASCII 
>      characters [RFC0020], it is possible to determine whether an octet
>      stream is UTF-8, UTF-16 (BE or LE), or UTF-32 (BE or LE) by looking
>      at the pattern of nulls in the first four octets.
>
>    ```
>       00 00 00 xx  UTF-32BE
>       00 xx 00 xx  UTF-16BE
>       xx 00 00 00  UTF-32LE
>       xx 00 xx 00  UTF-16LE
>       xx xx xx xx  UTF-8
>    ```

So it appears a JSON octet stream can be encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32 (in both their BE or LE variants, for the last two).

Once that is clear, `Section 2.5. Strings` explains how to handle those `\uXXXX` values in JSON strings:

> Any character may be escaped.  If the character is in the Basic
>   Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be
>   represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed
>   by the lowercase letter u, followed by four hexadecimal digits that
>   encode the character's code point.  The hexadecimal letters A though
>   F can be upper or lowercase.  So, for example, a string containing
>   only a single reverse solidus character may be represented as
>   "\u005C".

With more complete explanations for characters not in the [*Basic Multilingual Plane*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)).

> To escape an extended character that is not in the Basic Multilingual 
>   Plane, the character is represented as a twelve-character sequence,
>   encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair.  So, for example, a string
>   containing only the G clef character (U+1D11E) may be represented as
>   "\uD834\uDD1E".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you get this to work?  When I put my wstring as L"{\"type\":\"string\",\"value\":\"\\u9CE5\"},\n", wcout shows \u9CE5 for the output in that line.

Comment: And now https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259 states that "JSON text exchanged between systems that are not part of a closed ecosystem MUST be encoded using UTF-8"

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would use std::string to store UTF-8 and UTF-8 only.
If incoming JSON text does not contain any \uXXXX sequences, std::string can be used as is, byte to byte, without any conversion.

When you parse \uXXXX, you can simply decode it and convert it to UTF-8, effectively treating it as if it was true UTF-8 character in its place - this is what most JSON parsers are doing anyway (libjson for sure).

Granted, with this approach reading JSON with \uXXXX and immediately dumping it back using your library is likely to lose \uXXXX sequences and replace them with their true UTF-8 representations, but who really cares? Ultimately, net result is still exactly the same.

Comment: The `\u` escape sequences denote UTF-16 code units, so you cannot simply decode them without looking at at least two escape sequences.

Comment: @Philipp: such a shame too... they were sooo close.