# How to use Unicode characters in x.dump() in nolohmann::json?

Tags: c++, json, utf-8

I'm trying to use Unicode characters (like `משתמש לא רשום/קיים` and other languages).

But when I try to do `json_object.dump()`, it throws an exception:

> {_Data={_What=0x00c80b08 "[json.exception.type_error.316] invalid UTF-8 byte at index 1: 0xF9" _DoFree=...} }
> When

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using JSON = nlohmann::json;

int main() 
{
    std::string str = "משתמש לא רשום/קיים";
    JSON json_obj;
    json_obj["message"] = str;

    std::cout << json_obj.dump();
}
```

For some reason it works in the "minimal reproducible example", but not in my project. Maybe the problem is somwhere else, but I don't know where... 
**In one sentence: How to support other languages' characters in `nolohmann::json`?**

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].

Comment: This question is a duplicate of another question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107329/how-to-handle-unicode-values-in-json-strings

Comment: Do you really mean _"Unique characters"_? Not _Unicode_? nlohmann/json handles UTF-8 - which is what JSON is specified to contain. Is that what you have put in your `json_object`?

Comment: a@TedLyngmo I have in my project Hebrew Characters, which are UTF-8 I think

Comment: @Alon [Seems to work fine](https://godbolt.org/z/GqGh57W9b). Also, what do you mean by _"Unique"_ characters? Are you sure that your don't mean _Unicode_ characters?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Probably Unicode. And it doesn't work for me from some reason

Comment: What exception do you get? Can you show your code in a [mre]?

Comment: Where is the [mcve]?

Comment: @TedLyngmo {_Data={_What=0x00c80b08 "[json.exception.type_error.316] invalid UTF-8 byte at index 1: 0xF9" _DoFree=...} }

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. What do you mean?

Comment: @Alon that is not a [mcve]. Please show the actual code that you are using, and the actual JSON data you are working with

Comment: @Alon Also, instead of giving vital information as comments, you may update your question.

Comment: You said "Done" in the second comment, which to my understanding means that you have read about a [mre] and took action. But I don't see a [mre] in your question.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. now?

Comment: @Alon No, it's still not a reproducible example. What I showed in my link ([Seems to work fine](https://godbolt.org/z/GqGh57W9b)) was a [mre]. You can copy that and compile it, _as-is_. Please show a similarly short example that we can copy and compile, _as-is_.

Comment: @TedLyngmo ohhhhhh I got it. now?

Comment: @Alon Sure, that's minimal. Does that code actually throw an exception? It [works fine here](https://godbolt.org/z/n4rYYdW8n)

Comment: @TedLyngmo In my project - yes, not in the online compiler. I think there's a difference between what I did in the minimal code and my project, but I can't find the difference

Comment: Are you using MSVC?

Comment: @Alon Then I think some of your other code is corrupting the data so it's not valid UTF8 anymore.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I don't know, how to check it?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Looks fine to me in my code

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, VS19

Comment: @Alon _"VS19"_ - Ah... Ok, if you have those hebrew characters in your source code, I think you need to explicitly save the source code in UTF8 format

Comment: If you have Hebrew characters in your program source, you need to make sure that it is saved as UTF-8 **and** you use `/utf-8` command line switch. If you take your characters from a file, you need to debug your program and make sure you are reading it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nlohmann json works with UTF8 `std::string`(s) no matter your platform encoding.
It means that you should either encode your code files as UTF8 or convert `str` content to UTF8 at runtime.
This is the same for every string you pass to nlohmann or you get from nlohmann.
On unix, the platform encoding is generally UTF8.
If your program runs on windows however, the debugger and system API(s) probably expect that you store ANSI encoded text in `std::string`(s), which means you'll have to do manual conversions.